# Get a value by one of 2 keys

Tags: python

I have a dictionary. Each key is represented in one of 2 ways: short and long. I want to get the values of some of they keys. I can do this:

```
d = dict(....)
a = d["a"] or d["aaa"]
b = d["b"] or d["bbb"]
```

But it throws an exception when the key "`a`" doesn't exist, so it won't call `d["aaa"]` even it must exist if `d["a"]` doesn't. It can be solved easily, I know, but how can I do that in an elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use dict.get:

```
a = d.get("a", d.get("aaa"))
b = d.get("b", d.get("bbb"))
```

Note however that this will do a lookup of `"aaa"` and `"bbb"` even if `"a"` and `"b"` exist.

This works also (because `or` works e.g. for `None` and `str` etc.):

```
a = d.get("a") or d.get("aaa")
```

and does not do a second lookup if the first one succeeds.

Note that this does NOT work if `None` is a possible value associated to a key in your dict.

As @TimPietzcker points out, if you don't have `None` as a possible value, you can do:

```
a = d.get("a") or d["aaa"]
```

in order to get an exception if both keys do not exist.

Comment: `None` is not necessary, `get` will return `None` by default.

Comment: `d.get("a") or d.get("aaa")` only looks up `"aaa"` when necessary. Or `d.get("a") or d["aaa"]` in case `KeyError` should be raised if both keys don't exist.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Even in this case, the default value will be used only if `a` is not found in `d`, right?

Comment: thanks @thefourtheye for pointing out that the second argument to `get(..)` is not needed and to @TimPietzcker for updating the answer (I was just about to edit it in parallel :-) )

Comment: The problem with `or` is that it fails with any falsy, like `0`, `""` etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you often use such a structure, you can have a small `dict` wrapper similar to this:

```
class altdict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, (tuple, list)):
            for p in item:
                try:
                    return self[p]
                except KeyError:
                    pass
            raise KeyError, item
        return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
```

and then

```
d = altdict({
    'a'   :'aaa!',
    'bbb' :'bbb!',
})

print d['a', 'aaa'] # aaa!
print d['b', 'bbb'] # bbb!
print d['c', 'ccc'] # KeyError
```

Note that this works with arbitrary lists of "alternate" keys:

```
d['B', 'Bill',  'William'] # pretty nice
```

while a `.get` solution will turn into a nightmare very quickly:

```
d.get('a', d.get('b', d.get('c'))) # wtf?
```

Comment: +1, this also works in cases of dictionaries like `{"a": None, "aaa": 0}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the get method of a dictionary and provide a default value:

d.get("a", None)

This will return d["a"] if "a" is a key or None otherwise